# How to set up a Server that can be accessed by friends that's behind a Private IP from my ISP?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, isp, pfsense, private-network

My ISP hands out Private IP Addresses to everyone, so the IP I have is different from the one I get when I type in "what is my IP" in chrome.  I have requested (for the second time) to be given a Public IP Address, but if there is a way for me to use the Private IP Address instead for the server, that'd be a real help.  I'm not sure why they reverted me back to a Private IP Address, but if it continues, then I'll need to stick with the work-around.  My ISP says that there is no work-around and that has been the general consensus with my google searches.

Comment: Most residential ISPs have clauses in their agreements which say you are not allowed to run a server from your network to the Internet. It is unlikely that your ISP cares the least about your problem running a server. The RIRs ran out of IPv4 addresses to assign to the ISPs, so the ISPs are turning to CGN, assigning private addresses to the residential customers in order to save their precious public IPv4 addresses for businesses which are willing to pay a premium for public IPv4 addresses.

Comment: That's pretty enlightening...lol.  Thanks for the info.  I thought it was strange that they were assigning private IP Addresses.  I just assumed it was the difference between cable and fiber.  I didn't realize that ISP's would try to keep you from running a server.  It does make sense in case of a server that gets a lot of traffic, but I didn't figure a small home cloud server (which is all the rage right now ;) ) or a small game server with maybe 24 or so people would be that big a deal.  I do understand my not being that important, though.

Answer (score 1):

As Ron Maupin commented, if they did give you a public IP, they'd probably want to charge you for it.  The way around this for something like a gaming server with friends is to set up a VPN.  As far as easy ways to do that...

[Hamachi](https://www.vpn.net/) has been around for a long time.  It's fine if you are looking to connect with fewer than four people at a time (there was a 5-host limit on the free service, last I used it).

Apparently [DynVPN](https://www.dynvpn.com/) is an alternative.  Seems free and unlimited for the time being.

And there's the open-source [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/245-community-open-source-software-overview.html), with the usual caveats about the ease (or lack thereof) of setting up open-source software.

Comment: I had a buddy suggest I tell them that I was trying to setup remote access with a home security cam system.  Two others I know were able to get public IP Addresses for VPN with work.  They said it was easier for them to keep everyone behind private addresses.

I've heard of Hamachi, but the server I had setup got around the 5-host limit.  It's just a small Terraria server for me and my friends and I was looking to try other game servers as well through Steam, since I thought it was neat.